# How do I calculate changes in panel data in R

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data

I have a panel data set with two waves. I want to calculate the (possible) change from wave 1 to wave 2 of a selected variable and add the result as a new variable to the dataset.
Two challenges: There are a considerable number of respondents who participated either only in the first wave or only in the second wave. Also, there are many NAs, which together make the use of lag or diff function difficult I think.

Example:

```
RespondentID <- c("id_001","id_002","id_002","id_003", "id_004", "id_004", "id_005", "id_005")
Wave <- c(1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2)
Value <- c(2,2,3,4,3,1,NA,3)
panel <- cbind(RespondentID,Wave,Value)

panel

 RespondentID Wave Value
[1,] "id_001"     "1"  "2"  
[2,] "id_002"     "1"  "2"  
[3,] "id_002"     "2"  "3"  
[4,] "id_003"     "2"  "4"  
[5,] "id_004"     "1"  "3"  
[6,] "id_004"     "2"  "1"  
[7,] "id_005"     "1"  NA   
[8,] "id_005"     "2"  "3"
```

The result should look like this:

```
     RespondentID Wave Value Change
[1,] "id_001"     "1"  "2"   NA    
[2,] "id_002"     "1"  "2"   NA    
[3,] "id_002"     "2"  "3"   "1"   
[4,] "id_003"     "2"  "4"   NA    
[5,] "id_004"     "1"  "3"   NA    
[6,] "id_004"     "2"  "1"   "-2"  
[7,] "id_005"     "1"  NA    NA    
[8,] "id_005"     "2"  "3"   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a data structure that recognises the panel data property of your data and "panel-aware" functions. `pdata.frame` in package `plm` is one candidate. See the example below, picking up from your example (but putting the various variables via `data.frame` together first (your approach with `cbind` lumps the columns together but converts to a character)):

```
panel <- data.frame(RespondentID,Wave,Value)

library(plm)
pdata <- pdata.frame(panel, index = c("RespondentID", "Wave"))
pdata$Change <- diff(pdata$Value)
pdata
#>          RespondentID Wave Value Change
#> id_001-1       id_001    1     2     NA
#> id_002-1       id_002    1     2     NA
#> id_002-2       id_002    2     3      1
#> id_003-2       id_003    2     4     NA
#> id_004-1       id_004    1     3     NA
#> id_004-2       id_004    2     1     -2
#> id_005-1       id_005    1    NA     NA
#> id_005-2       id_005    2     3     NA
```

The `diff` on a pdata.frame's column is a panel-aware diff.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to have worked well on the original dataset. I had to convert all factor variables into numeric first (I did not have that in mind before).

Answer (score -1):

First I create the example data using the `data.frame` function instead of `cbind` since I would like to have the 'Value' column to have numeric values.

```
library(data.table)
RespondentID <- c("id_001","id_002","id_002","id_003", "id_004", "id_004", "id_005", "id_005")
Wave <- c(1,1,2,2,1,2,1,2)
Value <- c(2,2,3,4,3,1,NA,3)
panel <- data.frame(RespondentID,Wave,Value)

panel
```

I create a new panel by reshaping the panel data into a wide format.

```
new_panel <- as.data.table(panel)
new_panel <- dcast(new_panel,
                   RespondentID~Wave,
                   fill = NA_integer_,
                   value.var = c("Value"))
```

I change the column names to something meaningful

```
colnames(new_panel)[2:3] <- c("Value_1", "Value_2")
```

The transformed data looks like this.

```
new_panel
RespondentID Value_1 Value_2
1:       id_001       2      NA
2:       id_002       2       3
3:       id_003      NA       4
4:       id_004       3       1
5:       id_005      NA       3
```

Now I create the Change column and the result looks like below.

```
new_panel[,Change:=Value_2 - Value_1]
new_panel
  RespondentID Value_1 Value_2 Change
1:       id_001       2      NA     NA
2:       id_002       2       3      1
3:       id_003      NA       4     NA
4:       id_004       3       1     -2
5:       id_005      NA       3     NA
```

I hope this helps.