# With R, how can I create a variable that is the difference between the value of X in t and the value of X in t-1?

Tags: r, panel-data

I have panel data with universities as individuals across several years. Every university has a ranking(a numerical value between 1 and 100), that can evolve from one year to another. Consider this ranking value to be the "X" I am talking about in the title.

For each unique university, I want to create a variable, let's call it "diff", that would just be the difference between the ranking of university i in time t minus the ranking of university i in time t-1. This variable could allow me to track whether a university went up or down the rankings, or if it stayed at the same spot, compared to the previous year. Logically, the first observation of every univeristy should be NA.

I toyed around with the dplyr package, trying the following command :

```
mydata %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  arrange(Name, year) %>%
  mutate(diff = Rank - lag(Rank))
```

But it doesn't seem to work, I only get NAs when doing this.

What commands should I use to get the variable I want ?

Comment: If you have only one observation per 'Name', (as it is grouped) `lag` returns `NA` and thus the difference will be NA.  Maybe you need to remove the `group_by(Name)`

Comment: no need for `lag`, how about `mutate(mydiff = c(NA, diff(Rank)))`? (same effect)

Comment: Neither of your solutions work. But everytime I execute these commands, R prints my whole database in the console, which is usually doesn't do when creating a new variable. Maybe my code is not plugging the results properly in the "diff" column ?

Comment: You need to assign the output of your pipe chain. For example, `newdata <- group_by(Name)....` so it does not print to the console.

Comment: Thanks ! By doing this, deleting the `group_by(Name)` line, and adding the `mutate(mydiff = c(NA, diff(Rank)))` line, it worked !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I calculate changes in panel data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73566233/how-do-i-calculate-changes-in-panel-data-in-r)